# Defining a two way many to many in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Just starting in Python/Django framework so sorry if this is dumb... but i cant find any solution.

```
class Dealer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact)

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dealers = models.ManyToManyField(Dealer)
```

I have this relation set up however when I run SyncDB it doesnt work. It tells me that Contact is not defined on this line
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact)

Im more familiar with compiled languages. Is there anyway to tell python that the contact class exists, or better yet is there a special syntax im missing for defining this kind of relation.

Comment: ManyToMany fields are bidirectional. There's no need for them to both have a ManyToMany field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont see a need for a two way ManyToMany in both the models, as they are a `M:N` relationship (2 way relationship).

Your issue here is, `Contact` is not defined at the point of execution of this code:

```
contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact)
```

So You need to wrap it in quotes for it to work

```
contacts = models.ManyToManyField('Contact')
```

Documentation on that [can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

I would recommend the following models:

```
class Dealer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField('Contact')

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and It would do exactly what you are looking for.

You can read about [`ManyToMany`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) relationships here. The same link also covers how to handle `Reverse m2m queries`

Comment: I understand this but this way Dealer now has a contacts object. So I am able to do dealer.contacts.add(contact)

however if I want to do it the other way contact.dealer.add(contact). How would I do that if I do not have the object defined in the class

Comment: In the manytomany relationship link I posted in the answer, search for `Reverse m2m queries` - It shows you how to deal with reverse manytomany relationships

Comment: I would recommend changing `contacts` to `contacts = models.ManyToManyField('Contact', related_name="dealers")`.

Comment: ... or you could put `dealers = models.ManyToManyField(Dealer, related_name="contacts")` in `Contact` and remove `contacts` from `Dealer`. This is my preferred choice since I prefer not to use the quoted form of a relation unless I absolutely have to. In either case, you use `Dealer.contacts` to go one way and `Contact.dealers` to go the other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a two way ManyToMany both, you just only need to do this:

```
class Dealer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField('Contact', blank=True)

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dealers = models.ManyToManyField('Dealer', through=Dealer.projects.through, blank=True)
```

I guess it will work to you.